# Changing default version of GNU Make in Red-hat Ubuntu

Tags: linux, path, gnu-make, gnu

Currently I have GNU Make version 3.82 and I need GNU Make 4.x or higher. I do not have sudo privileges so I downloaded latest make-4.2.93 version from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/ in my local folder `/home/username/local/bin/make-4.2.93`. I tried to do following in order to add this to my path:

I added this line in my `.tcshrc` file:

`set path=( $path /home/username/local/bin/make-4.2.93)`

But my default make version still is the same old one.

```
make --version

GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

How can this be made right?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to put the new path before any path that contains the original `make`. Try: `set path=(/home/username/local/bin/make-4.2.93 $path)`

Comment: I tried your suggestion `set path=(/home/username/local/bin/make-4.2.93 $path)`, It still shows older version

Comment: Then do basic debugging. Show result of: `which make` and `echo $PATH`. Also, did you actually build the new `make`? The download is source code not binaries.

Comment: `which make` shows `/usr/bin/make` And `echo $PATH` shows ```/home/username/local/bin/make-4.2.93:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:home/username/local/bin/make-4.2.93:/home/username/local/bin/make-4.2.93```

Comment: I suspect you have not actually built the new `make`. Please confirm. Show the the output of running the new `make`.

Comment: Ok. That could be possible. I downloaded the tarball and untar it using `tar -xvf make-4.2.93.tar.gz` command. I am not sure how can I build it. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224004/discussion-between-kiran-and-kaylum).

Comment: Why are you using 4.2.93?  That is a prerelease version, which should not be used except for testing.  You should be using the released version, 4.3.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you. Actually 4.3 also had similar issues. I was able to build `make-4.0` version and it works perfectly now. My default GNU Make is 4.0 now after setting the path.

Comment: All releases of GNU make are the same: they only release source code.  The INSTALL file is boilerplate that comes with all GNU packages.  I seem to recall a bug filed that somehow the INSTALL file was left out of the 4.3 source package, but as I say it's exactly the same for all releases.

Comment: I see. I could not find any INSTALL file in 4.3 version. But I was able to get 4.2 as well. Thanks again!